# AddIdentity must be called on the service collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

i have a problem running my **Asp.net core** site on **Debian 8** using **netcore** **1.1.1** with version **1.0.3**

So i made a site using **Asp.net core** on my **windows 10** platform using **VS2017** and published it by `dotnet publish -c release`

Then i uploaded my project using FTP to **Debian 8** and then i wrote

```
dotnet Altram.Web.Donate.dll

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: AddIdentity must be called on the service collection.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.BuilderExtensions.UseIdentity(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Altram.Web.Donate.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in /mnt/d/Development/C#/Visual Studio/Altram System/Altram.Web.Donate/Startup.cs:line 104
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Altram.Web.Donate.Program.Main(String[] args) in /mnt/d/Development/C#/Visual Studio/Altram System/Altram.Web.Donate/Program.cs:line 10
Aborted
```

in **Startup.cs** at **ConfigureServices method** i have

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info());
            options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath,
                "Altram.Web.Donate.xml"));
        });

        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(builder =>
        {
            builder.UseNpgsql(Configuration["Data:AltramDatabase"],
                options => options.MigrationsAssembly("Altram.Web.Donate"));
        });

        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContextCache>(builder =>
            builder.UseInMemoryDatabase());

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
            .AddErrorDescriber<ErrorDescriber>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 46;
        });

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDataInitializer();
        services.DomainInitializer();

        services.Initialize(links =>
            {
                links.Login = Configuration["Robokassa:RobokassaLogin"];
                links.Mode = Configuration["Robokassa:RobokassaMode"];
                links.Pass1 = Configuration["Robokassa:RobokassaPass1"];
                links.Pass2 = Configuration["Robokassa:RobokassaPass2"];
            });

        services.AddLogging();
    }
}
```

and **Configure Method**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentity();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

So it give me that error at **app.UseIdentity();** Line

and **it's working very good without any problems on Windows 10**.

*I use PostgresSql with my project*.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: What line does the error occur on? Does the line that the error occurred on run before or after your services.AddIdentity call?

Comment: @mason I think its on UseIdentity line because it's working well on my Windows dev enviroment

Comment: You do not resolve bugs by assuming things. Verify exactly what's happening. Add Console.WriteLine statements or logging etc. Determine without a doubt exactly what is happening. For that matter, you need to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code here is not complete.

Comment: @mason I made some tests with some web test project and tried to run it on windows 10 bash, with UseIdentity that i use, so it ran perfectly without errors, i tried to change the database and some parametrs at csproj file, but that did not help me, anyway i used some of WriteLine methods and now i know that the error at line  app.UseIdentity(); And i added some code to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my error by removing and put it outside of the if brackets

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
    .AddErrorDescriber<ErrorDescriber>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

From the if(Enviroment.IsDevelopment()) code because when i start dotnet from the terminal it starts at production Enviroment mode, so addIdentity won't work.